# Flutter module code not showing up on github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, flutter

I have a Flutter based Android app. The app used to be completely native. Then I decided to integrate Flutter. I use the built in option in Android Studio to push my code to git. Now since the Flutter module is at the parent directory of the app, pushing to git doesn't push the flutter code. What could I do to make Android Studio push Flutter code as well so that the code can be seen on the Git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repository you are pushing includes a Flutter subfolder with itself a `Flutter/.git` directory, then that Flutter folder would be a nested repository.

Only its gitlink (tree sha1) would be recorded, not its folder content.

You would need to `git rm --cached Flutter` (no trailing slash) and remove the Flutter/.git folder in order to be able to add and commit the all Flutter *content*.

Or you would need to use submodule in order to add Flutter as a full external repository reference: see an example in [`flutter/flutter` issue 3770](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3770#issuecomment-358745241).

Comment: There is no .git folder in flutter module. Still flutter module changes are not being registered.

Comment: @NullByte08 Can you check what does `git check-ignore -v -- Flutter/a-File-Inside-Flutter` return?

Comment: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: I am trying git submodules now.  Do I need to `git init` inside the flutter module directory?

Comment: @NullByte08 the command should be executed on level above the .git folder.

Comment: @NullByte08 And if flutter itself can be declared as a submodule within your project, then you don't need to `git init` it.

Comment: there is no .git folder inside the flutter module's directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221983/discussion-between-nullbyte08-and-vonc).

Comment: @NullByte08 If the error message reports a `.git` folder, there should be one (keep in mind, it is hidden by default)